# Get error message from SQLCMD in PYTHON

Tags: python, subprocess, sqlcmd

I'm really close. This gives the output of the query, but I need to retrieve only error messages. I feel like one little adjustment will do it...

```
import subprocess

command_process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['sqlcmd', '-E', '-V1', '-S', '1070854A\AISP', '-i', 'NewStructures.sql'],
    shell=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)
command_output = command_process.communicate()[0]

print command_output
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

```
import subprocess

command_process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['sqlcmd', '-E', '-V1', '-S', '1070854A\AISP', '-i', 'NewStructures.sql'],
    shell=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
)
command_output = command_process.communicate()[0]

print command_process.stderr.read()
```